# How do I run a modified github repo in Firebase?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I found a python-based repo I'd like to modify and then run as follows:

1. The user sends an audio file to Firebase backend
2. Firebase applies the functions in the github repo
3. Firebase then sends the modified audio file back to the user

Where exactly would the modified repo live? Not sure where to start.

Comment: [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) might be useful. Firebase version supposed NodeJS only atm. You can then call the function from your client application.

Comment: @Dharmaraj ok I've set up cloud functions. Now where do I put the modified repo? Just inside the functions folder? And if so, how do I write a typescript function that can access that repo?

Comment: If you are familiar with python, you should at least go through the [existing codelabs for python](https://developers.google.com/learn/topics/python)